# Running Excel query row by row

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have made a following query in excel powerquery:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    IDname = Vir{0}[IDname],
    query = "exec procOderBySampleID '"& IDname &"' ",
    target = Sql.Database("XXX-YYYY\YY76", "SQLtable", [Query=query])
in
    target
```

It returns result for a first row in IDname column. I would like a query to run row by row and return results for all the values in IDname column. Combining values with comma in between them `IDname = Text.Combine(List.Transform(Source[IDname], Text.From), ", "),` and passing them to query does not work, so the solution would need to work row by row.

Sample:

```
A1 IDname
A2 78-001
A3 78-002
A4 78-003
```

query should run stored procedure for one value after another (A2 then A3 then A4) and return a table:

```
A1 IDname  Refnumber   User
A2 78-001        4    Mat
A3 78-002        7    Kid
A4 78-003        5    Luc
```

With current code I only get A1 and A2 as result.

Comment: Sample data with expected output would help.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Where from refnumber and user value coming?